# Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error. How to determine source?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-addins

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.
I have Resharper 2016.2.2 and various other VSIX plugins installed.

After about 10~30 minutes of use, a few things may happen (this is quite vague):

1. Inability to close visual studio, pressing close shows the "Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error."  I have to task manager/kill app to close and restart.
2. Partial loss of keyboard,  backspace etc stop working, Ctrl-F4 stops, but regular alphanumeric typing works. (but other system features like saving files stops as well)

Searching for symptoms everyone seems to allude to something but none of the options found appear to work.  Is there a more intelligent approach to determining (i assume it is a plugin at fault)  which plugin/extension is causing the error. (Ie does VS dump a log file of errors or can I run in debug mode or something ) to attempt to isolate the offending 'thing'.

Edit: 28/11/2016.  Uninstalled all plugins + resharper.  Still occurring (the "unexpected error" and loss of keyboard operation).   Seems to like a reinstall to fix. Ugh.

Comment: Binary search. Turn half of them off, see if the problem continues. Repeat.

Comment: Yeah thanks, going through deduction now.. Looks like it may not even be a plugin :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you believe the problem lies within a plugin or recent update then simply undo that update or disable any recently installed plugins. Test VS after these changes in hopes to narrow down the plugin causing the issue. If that doesn't fix your problem visual studio does have a debug mode but you must download the Microsoft installer from their official website and select the debug option in the installer menu. if that fails too then i suggest just uninstalling VS and attempt to install the software again.